# How to pass a value twice or thrice based on the count in Scenario Outline Example in Pytest BDD

Tags: parameterization, pytest-bdd

How to pass a value twice or thrice based on the count in Scenario Outline Example in Pytest BDD

Scenario outline:

When User selects
And User selects

Examples:

```
| Fruit    | Vegetable |
| Apple: 2 | Brinjal: 3 |
```

Scenario outline:

When User selects
And User selects

Examples:

```
| Fruit    | Vegetable |
| Apple: 2 | Brinjal: 3 |
```